# Credit Card Hijack malicious javascript code continuously insert by someone in my site under HTML Head -> Miscellaneous Scripts

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, security, credit-card, core-hacks

Someone continuously  inserts Credit Card Hijack malicious javascript into to my site under

> system->configuration->General->Design->HTML Head->Miscellaneous Scripts.

**Note: I changed every thing like admin password, FTP, MAGMI everything.**

But Still, insert Credit Card Hijack malicious javascript code.

How can I prevent my site from any other attack?

> Is any Security extensions available?

Comment: i hope this link will useful for you please check  https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=Two-Factor+Authentication&pl=0

Comment: hello everyone, may I know what is the loop someone inserts script to my site.

Comment: please check the index.php of your site and file modified date.

Comment: @NAGARAJUKASA : No changes in index.php

Answer (score 5):

1. Scan with Magereport.com
2. Scan with Magescan.com
3. Do a full virus (eval) scan on the server, or ask your hosting company to do so.
4. Go to app/etc/applied-patched and make sure that **EVERY SINGLE CRITICAL PATCH IS** **installed**. Basically all the grey checks you see in Magereport.com, double-check and make sure that respetive patches are installed.

   5. As precaution, make sure /admin, /downloader, and /rss, is hidden or disabled in .htaccess. They can be used for bruteforcing.

We need to find the cause, since it looks the code is being injected via bypassing all the admin passwords. I highly suspect 2 reasons: 1. Missing patch. 2. 3rd party Extension is being compromised. First one is more likely.

Comment: When i try to install Security patch 5344 (Shoplift)  i get error like,,, see my error :  http://pasted.co/97e53a7f   password : kiy258

Comment: How can i solve this error

Comment: It looks like 5344 is installed that's why its giving you Hunk errors. Check again in  app/etc/applied-patches, it could have slightly different number like 5345.

Comment: Here you can check 5344 installation using official magento scan
https://magento.com/security-patch

Comment: what are the values i enter here, website url then?

Comment: but magereport.com return : https://snag.gy/deC4XN.jpg

Comment: That is right, Magereport doesn't validate 5344 because it doesn't know your admin URL, since it cant validate it shows grey field.

Comment: Go to  the link I provided earlier via official Magneto 5344 security check and type in your website and /admin path (it could be different in your case).

Answer (score 1):

We've been seeing more and more Magento stores being targeted by hackers. We've noticed that hackers are usually targeting Magento 1.9.X and modifying the following files:

app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Block/Checkout/Payment/Method/Ccsave.php
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Cc.php
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php

Here's a detailed post, I believe it'll be a great add-on for your readers to follow post your article: https://www.getastra.com/blog/911/how-to-remove-fix-magento-opencart-credit-card-malware-hack/

Answer (score 0):

Scan your website here: https://www.magereport.com/ or https://magento.com/security-patch and install required patch and take required action as suggest by scan report.

Answer (score 0):

When you do all suggested then check this extension https://www.extensionsmall.com/mage-fence-security.html

Magefence scan your Magento from backend and search trought php files, which Magereport can't. It has also many other useful security featires.